# Google Ecommerce code issues

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

Is there any issue in this google ecommerce code. We had tons of transactions but none showing
up in the ecommerce...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        try{
          var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXX-1");
      pageTracker._trackPageview();
          pageTracker._addTrans(
            "429",            // order ID - required
            "louiseh",  // affiliation or store name
            "11.65",           // total - required
            "3.15",           // shipping
            "Santa Clara",        // city
            "California",      // state or province
          );
    //Add each items in the order

          pageTracker._addItem(
            "429",  // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
            "99",           // SKU/code - required
            "Sandwich WrapIt!",        // product name
            "Home, Garden & Pets",   // category or variation
            "8.5",          // unit price - required
        "1",
          );
    //Now submit the transaction
    pageTracker._trackTrans(); //submits transaction to the Analytics server
       } catch(err) {}
    </script> 


<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxx-1");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ecommerce code is being executed before the `ga.js` script is loaded so the `_gat` object isn't available yet. An error is being thrown but it's not being shown in the error console because it's enclosed in a `try/catch` block. If you reorder the script blocks then it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try{
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXX-1");
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
        pageTracker._addTrans(
        "429",            // order ID - required
        "louiseh",  // affiliation or store name
        "11.65",           // total - required
        "3.15",           // shipping
        "Santa Clara",        // city
        "California"      // state or province
    );

        //Add each items in the order
        pageTracker._addItem(
        "429",  // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
        "99",           // SKU/code - required
        "Sandwich WrapIt!",        // product name
        "Home, Garden & Pets",   // category or variation
        "8.5",          // unit price - required
        "1"
    );
        //Now submit the transaction
        pageTracker._trackTrans(); //submits transaction to the Analytics server
    } catch(err) {}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ewan. I pushed the changes, and waiting the results to get reflected in Google e-commerce as it takes ~24 hours.

Comment: So I changed the order and code still doesn't seem to work? Is there a way we can debug this code. We had ~10 sales for last two days but none of them got reported by analytics

Comment: You can see what's being sent to GA from the browser using Firefox live HTTP headers or the GA debugging extension for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Comment: Yes unique order ID for each sale with products sold in each order.